# Navigate to a specific page with a particular condition

Tags: c#, uwp

How do I navigate to a specific page with a particular condition? For example if I click the back button and the previous page is the store page, then navigate to the page store, whereas if the previous page is another page, the page to the home page.
I tried the code below but it did not work:

```
private void backButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Store)) == true)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Store));
        }
        else
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make use of `BackStack` List of frame

```
var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (frame != null)
      {
           var lastPage = frame.BackStack.LastOrDefault();
           if (lastPage != null && lastPage.SourcePageType.Equals(typeof(Store)))
           {

           }

      }
```

Comment: in code:
if(lastPage!=null && lastPage.SourcePageType.typeof(Store);
display error message: "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" and "Identifier expected". How to solve this?

Comment: Did you fix the syntax issue? i mean semicolon should be removed,such things? Updated the answer.